# Edit an item in a ListView using Simple Adapter

Tags: android, listview, simpleadapter

I have a ListView populated using a SimpleAdapter:

```
List<Map<String, String>> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
listItems.add(createItemMap(R.string.rename_mobtag, R.string.rename_mobtag_help));
listItems.add(createItemMap(R.string.change_icon, R.string.change_icon_help));
listItems.add(createItemMap(R.string.become_invisible, R.string.become_invisible_help));

ListView mobtagSettings = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobtag_settings);
    final String[] fromMapKey = new String[]{TITLE_KEY, HELP_KEY};
    final int[] toLayoutId = new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};
    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, fromMapKey, toLayoutId);
    mobtagSettings.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

I need to update the TextViews for a particular item in response to an external event (hence I cannot use the Click listener for that). How can I do get the TextViews so I can change their texts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just make a new list containing the change and update that list in the adapter and call notifyDatasetChanged method

Answer (score 1):

For that particular TextView item, do you know the position/index of that item in your list? You might want to create your own custom adapter which will include a update function to that particular item in the list of the adapter so that you can update the Textview of that item.

You can refer to http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown_custom where the writer have quite a lot of stuff regarding list view, such as custom adapter and etc. Hope it help.

Cheers